# Objective-C: testing for an unassigned (undefined) variable?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, variables

If I've created these two variables:

```
NSDecimalNumber *myNum;
NSString *myString;
```

how do I later test whether an object has been assigned to them yet or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If they aren't in a class, you must assign `nil` as a default value if you want to use this. In a class, that will be automatic.

To test if they have an object associated with them, compare them against `nil`: `if (myNum != nil) // myNum is an object`.

Also note that when an object is deallocated, references to it still exist, so when you release ownership of these objects it is good to set them back to `nil`: `myNum = nil;`

Comment: To clarify, instance variables and `static` variables get initialized to `nil` for free. Local variables and non-`static` global variables don't.

Comment: Note that with ARC, local object pointers are also initialized to nil.

Answer (score 1):

Set it to `nil` to start with:

```
NSDecimalNumber *myNum = nil;
```

Then use:

```
if (myNum == nil) { ... you haven't set it yet ... }
```

`nil` is the ObjC way of doing null objects (those that do not refer to an actual object).

Comment: `nil` and `NULL` are the same value, they just may be slightly different types (`nil` an `id`, `NULL` a `void *`). You can send a message to `NULL`; you may get a warning (or not), but it won't crash.

Comment: Thanks, @Peter, I actually meant the equivalent operation in C or C++ which would result in dereferencing a null pointer, but I've taken that bit out entirely since it didn't really add to the answer that much.